# .Net Core API start URL

Tags: .net, .net-core, port

This is my `Program.cs`:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var host = new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseKestrel()
        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .UseUrls("http://localhost:9020")
        .UseIISIntegration()
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        //.UseApplicationInsights()
        .Build();

    host.Run();
}
```

which used to run on port `9020` as specified under `UseUrls()`. For some reason now when I start the program, it gets served on port `54033` and the only thing (I think) I've changed is adding:

```
<RuntimeIdentifiers>win10-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
```

to my `.csproj` for release, but I don't see how that should affect the port on which the service is running. Is there somewhere else I can check for the issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under Properties of your project you can find launchSettings.json. Here you can define profiles in which your app can be started. ApplicationUrl setting set url for the app.

[image]

Example json:

```
 "profiles": {
"IIS Express": {
  "commandName": "IISExpress",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "launchUrl": "api",
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  }
},
"RunInCommandPrompt": {
  "commandName": "Project",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "launchUrl": "api",
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  },
  "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:19556"
}
}
```

Comment: That works...but now I'm wondering why isn't the `Program.cs` option overriding it? What's the point of changing it on 2 places?

Comment: I don't recommend hard-coding urls in code, setting it via settings is much cleaner way. Reason why code from Program.cs gets overwritten is because you were launching you app from Visual Studio, and configs for that are stored in launchSettings.json  file.